Can i create a local VM exactly like an Amazon EC2-T2-nano instance?
What I am trying to do:
Create a local virtual machine on my Windows 11 machine which is exactly like an Amazon EC2-T2-Nano instance.
Why I am trying to do this:
I would like to create this machine (possibly many instances of it) so that I can perform local load testing in an environment exactly like the one I would be purchasing from AWS but without spending the money on actual EC2 instances.
Here is what I have tried:

Follow these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2/ug/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html

Problems I had trying to follow those instructions:

I could not run either genisoimage or hdiutil because those don't work on windows.  I attempted to run a windows version of such a tool but was not successful so instead I installed a new VM using Virtualbox (a basic Ubuntu 24 instance) which allowed me to run genisoimage and create the seed.iso file.  After much work I figured out how to make a shared drive between my host machine and this VM to get the file onto the host machine.

Why did I do this: because I don't want to create the AWS VM on my Ubuntu VM I want to create it on my host VM. I figured i would need the file there.
Great, now I have a seed.iso file on my host/Windows box.  The next step unfortunately is to use VMware vSphere which is some sort of external tool.  This was not my goal.  My goal was to create a VM on my personal Windows machine.  I tried to do the same thing in VMware Workstation however the instructions to 'create a new datastore for the seed.iso file' don't make sense in regards to VMware Workstations (I presume they make sense in vSphere).
I cannot follow the Oracle VirtualBox instructions because they require an .iso file which i do not have.  (Correction, I do have a seed.iso file, but this is not an operating system,  I can actually load that in VirtualBox but it immediately fails saying that the system does not have an operating system)
Next attempt:
After googling around and just messing around with VirtualBox I noticed that it has an "Import Virtual Appliance" function in it which allows you to select an .ova file (which I actually have as I downloaded this from the original instructions).  Going down this path, VirtualBox seems to have made a VM using the OVA file, however when I boot this thing up all it does is barfs out some logs into the terminal then it shuts itself down.
What other options could I try to get this working?

I see that someone has already edited out your editorializing about this site. Just so it's clear: Stack Overflow is for programming Q&A. Questions about VMs, VirtualBox, etc don't fit here - they'd fit better on (probably) [sf] or [su]. Just be sure to read the guidelines there first.

Here is the answer:

Go to the instructions I posted above.  In those instructions are a link to an .ova file for the amazon image: https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/os-images/2.0.20241217.0/vmware/  (again, copy it now because Amazon likes to change their instructions often)

Install VMware Workstation

Install VirtualBox

Install any linux VM such as Ubuntu 24 on the Virtualbox instance

In your host machine, create a folder called seedconfig and in that folder create files called meta-data and user-data exactly as the instructions say (note these files do not have extensions)

In your Ubuntu machine, open a terminal and install genisoimage with the following command apt-get install genisoimage (don't try to download it from a webpage you'll just go into a loop downloading other garbage)

I'm a bit unclear on how I did this (because I've already removed the Ubuntu machine) but I think I created a duplicate folder with the meta-data and user-data files like I mentioned above but in the ubuntu machine.

from a terminal on the ubuntu machine navigate to the folder you just created and run the genisoimage command as the tutorial suggests: genisoimage -output seed.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data (this will generate a seed.iso file on your ubuntu machine

get that file over into your host machine somehow.  I struggled with this because I couldn't just email it to myself (gmail flagged the file as a virus) and I couldn't create a shared drive right away because the instructions for doing that didn't work.  I honestly don't know how i got the shared drive to work but I did and eventually copied it over to the host machine and put the file in the same location as the other two files on the host machine.

Using VMWare, create a virtual machine by pointing to the .ova file you downloaded earlier, run the machine.  Note, you will not be able to log into this machine because the username/password is not set up yet.

While the machine is running, go to the configuration settings in VMware and find the place where you can add hardware.  Add a new CD/DVD device and point that device at your seed.iso file.  Make sure you check the boxes for 'Connected' and 'Connect at power on'

Reboot the machine

After it reboots you can now log in with your ec2-user and whatever password you put into your user-data file (the system will immediately ask for a new password)



Ive edited out your whining. If you don't like this site you don't have to use it. If you have concerns about the way the site operates you can raise them on [meta].

If your intention is to "perform local load testing in an environment exactly like the one I would be purchasing from AWS" then the steps are missing the most important part, which is configuring the virtual hardware to match the configuration of the t2.nano instance. That instance type has limited CPU, RAM and network bandwidth but, more importantly, it is a Burstable performance instance that behaves differently under sustained load. This type of instance is not recommended for Production loads.

I further edited this answer to remove the entire preamble, which was thick with condescension toward the Community. None of this is appropriate in an answer.
